# ADB over Bluetooth Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, adb, tethering

I have no WIFI, I have no cable connection available.

Is there hope for me to connect my device to ADB?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

With the latest releases of Cyanogenmod (7.2 and 9) and presumably some other roms the option of *adb over network* has arrived.

Similar to *[ADB over WIFI](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ryosoftware.adbw&hl=en)* which has been available for a while, it pretty much does the same.

- Enable Bluetooth on your laptop and device
- Pair them
- Connect from your laptop to your device via Bluetooth PAN (Personal Area Network)
- Enable the *ADB over Network* setting (Settings/Applications/Development)
- Find out your IP address from the terminal (`busybox ifconfig` should do)

  - Non-root: check the `default gateway` on your computer, it should be your device's IP
- Connect your device from your computer via `adb connect xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`
- Enjoy.

Make sure to disable the ADB over Network setting after your done with it to avoid Mobile Internet ADB stuff. Just disable the Bluetooth when your done and it should be fine.

Bonus part is, that while your paired and developing for this, you are able to use the devices mobile internet as well. (if you have coverage, of course)

This is only a partial solution since it needs the device to be both rooted and running a rom that offers that particular setting. I can only assume that it can be done some other way from the terminal, but I'm not savvy enough to manage it.

Comment: @Juan Where do you see *ADB over Network* in `Settings` > `Applications` > `Development`? I checked multiple phones (CM6, CM7 included) and there is no mention of such option.

Comment: @an00b: I have that option on Cyanogenmod 10.1 Android 4.2.2.

Comment: if you don't have a usb cable, use https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.wifiadb&hl=en

Comment: The two "ADB over WiFi" apps linked here (one in the answer and one in a comment) both require root. This one does not (and it has no advertising, at least not yet): https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=za.co.henry.hsu.adbwirelessbyhenry BUT you need to have successfully connected via USB at least once since the last reboot, so it's only good if you have USB cable at home but don't want to take it on a trip. It's not Bluetooth, but if you have a WiFi adapter you can set it up as an access point (search for how to set up <insert your operating system here> as an access point if unsure)

Comment: @JonathanHendler it is for WiFi! If phone not connected to any WiFi access point then it's useless, we are talking about Bluetooth connection (we don't have WiFi, router)...