# Debug app using ADB over Bluetooth for on an Android-x86 netbook

Tags: android, tcp, bluetooth, adb, tethering

I managed to set a nicely working Android-x86 on my netbook, with Bluetooth enabled and paired (!) with my Windows 7 development workstation.

I was initially hoping to use adb with it just as I am doing with real phones, via USB. So I plugged in a dedicated USB male-to-male cable and... nothing happened. Turns out Android-x86 doesn't support connection via USB cable.

I then found [great instructions](http://www.cidtux.com/1/post/2012/07/how-to-connect-adb-through-wifi-using-wifiadb-for-android-android-x86.html) on how to do [ADB over WiFi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3623727). The problem is that I have WiFi on my Android-x86 netbook but not on my Windows 7 desktop PC. I do have the option of buying a WiFi dongle but I prefer a more immediate solution.

I happen to have Bluetooth working both on my Android-x86 netbook and on my PC, so I was hoping to find a solution that can allow me to proceed quickly with [ADB over Bluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11129818). I found very encouraging instruction here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11129818 but unfortunately the so called `ADB over Network` is nowhere to be found on my Android-x86 device.

Any tip or idea how to make ADB over Bluetooth work for on my Android-x86 netbook?

I believe that if I can make my Android-x86's bluetooth have an IP address, I can go from there, but how do I do that? (`ifconfig` doesn't work in Android's Terminal Emulator).

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11129817/588306).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While [this blog post](http://fomori.org/blog/?p=300) shows a way to have ADB over Bluetooth, it probably works for devices running CM only. Thus it seems that until further notice, it isn't possible to do the same on Android-x86 netbooks.

Answer (score 1):

Was the dedicated cable one of those host-to-host cables, or was it a OTG cable?  Do you have any reason to expect either device to support OTG?

(If it's a host-to-host cable it'll have some electronics in the middle, if it's OTG then it'll really just be a cable)

Comment: It's a simple USB cable like [this one](http://r.ebay.com/v01leI). The PC definitely supports OTG because I can adb with it to many phones I have using a simple micro USB cable like [this one](http://r.ebay.com/akvOyF). As I mentioned in my question, I gave up on the idea of using a cable because I believe Android-x86 doesn't support it for some reason. The question is really about **Bluetooth** but +1 for being the first one trying to help.