# WiFi debugging without USB

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, wifi

I am developing on a Sony Xperia Z3 Compact at the moment, which now has a broken USB slot. I read about how to connect my phone to Android Studio via WiFi, but all the solutions I found were requiring the phone to be connected via USB in the first step. My device is **not rooted**!

Is there any way to get the connection to Android Studio going without connecting via USB first?

Comment: Have you read the following yet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11129817/adb-over-bluetooth-android ?

Comment: This would require to have CyanogenMod running on my phone. However, I am using the regular ROM, so I cannot use this solution.