# Can I debug apps using Bluetooth instead of USB?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, usb, processing

Is it possible to debug apps on Android using Bluetooth?

I am working with Processing 4.1.1 and I'd like to run my apps on my Android phone. Processing allows to run apps on devices which are connected through USB debugging, but there is something wrong with my cable/device as it is constantly disconnecting.

> Other than using an emulator, could I debug through Bluetooth? If yes, how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ADB over Bluetooth Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11129817/adb-over-bluetooth-android). If that doesn't work, simply googling your question yields many results.

Comment: Why not wifi? https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#connect-to-a-device-over-wi-fi

Answer (score 0):

You can do it over WiFi using adb. Your phone and PC have to be on the same network.

Just enter this command in your cmd:
`adb connect IP_ADDRESS_OF_YOUR_PHONE`

You have to be in the directory where your adb is for this to work.